# Adding to values to an array

Tags: php

I have an array `$products`

```
Array
    (
        [1000] => Array
            (
                [key] => 1000
                [name] => Cat
            )

    )

        [2000] => Array
            (
                [key] => 2000
                [name] => Dog
            )

    )
```

and I retrieve an external array via a service (`$extProducts`), I want to modify the array(`$products`) so that it is structured like this:

```
Array
   (
       [1000] => Array
           (
               [key] => 1000
               [name] => Cat
               [ID] => 77
           )

   )

       [2000] => Array
           (
               [key] => 2000
               [name] => Dog
               [ID] => 9

           )

   )
```

I have tried the following:

```
foreach ($extProducts as $extProduct){
   $product['ID'] = $extProduct["ID"];
   array_push($products, $product);
}
```

This just completely changes the array, and not giving me what I need please can anyone help.
---------------------Update----

Sorry I wasn't clear before, the external array is actually returned via json which I decode to make an array. I cannot use key as the key from the `$extProducts` as this does not match `$products`.

Also nb.
`$extProduct["ID"];` would actually be `$extProduct["Data"]["context"]["UpdatedOrder"]["Items"]["ID"];`

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "StatusDesc": "Success",
    "Data": {
        "context": {
            "$id": "1",
            "UpdatedOrder": {
                "$id": "2",
                },
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "ID": "4",
                        "Price": 6.99,
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": "7",
                        "Price": 1.39,
                    }
                ],
            "ApiResult": {
                "$id": "9",
                "TransactionId": "xxx",
                "ResultCode": 0,
                "ResultMessage": "Success"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Work with the keys : foreach($extProducts as $key => $extProduct) and then you use $product[$key]["ID"]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but not quite what i'm looking for I have made updates to the question

Comment: So where the `key` is comming from? 1000/2000. How do you define it?

Comment: The problem is that there is nothing linking the `$products` array and the JSON. There are no common keys that you can match them up on.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($extProducts as $id=>$extProduct){
   $extProducts[$id]["ID"]=123; //reference your ID here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but not quite what i'm looking for I have made updates to the question

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
foreach($products as $key => $product){

  foreach($key as $mod_product){
     $mod_product['ID'] = $extProduct["ID"];
     array_push($products, $mod_product);


 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get item id from JSON array:-

```
 $itemID = array();
 foreach($extProduct["Data"]["context"]["Items"] as 
 $itemId) {
        array_push($itemID,$itemId["ID"];
 }
```

Now format your result array:-

```
  $resultArray = Array();
  $i = 0;

  foreach($products as $product){

      foreach($product as $key => $mod_product){

          array_push($mod_product,$itemID[$i]);
          array_push($resultArray,$mod_product);
          $i++;

       }

    }
```

Try this answer. I think, you'll get the desired result.